# how to ignore current selection from ivy when my typed text matches one

Tags: files, ivy

I run into this issue from time to time when I want to create a new file but the new name matches a pattern already so my Ivy auto-complete setup will pick the matched option when I press `Enter` instead of just directly using the text I have entered and I am wondering if there is a solution for this that allows me to use what I have typed rather than the Ivy selected complete option.

See this example:

I have a directory with a file in it called `file.txt`.  Now I want to make a new file that is just called `file`.  So, `C-f`, then type `file`, but now Ivy has selected `file.txt` and I can't just create `file` this way by pressing enter.

[image]

Similarly, suppose I wanted to rename `file.txt` to `file` in Dired.  I have exactly the same problem:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`C-M-j` (ivy-immediate-done) - exit with the current action, calling it on the current input instead of the current candidate. This is useful especially when creating new files or directories - often the input will match an existing file, which you don’t want to select.

source:
https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/f0b2bc618a84d25c0b3d05314d5d5693c27b2d3e/doc/ivy-help.org#key-bindings-for-single-selection

Comment: Crazy key binding (( I which they had better defaults.